# Is there an any specific way to stop execution of request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I've one API which triggers one process on the backend and the API returns with success msg and unique request-id, API doesn't care whether the background process finishes or not.

Now I want another API through which I can stop the execution of the above running process.

I'm having a unique request-id for each request so I want to stop the execution of the process for that particular request-id only. **Is there any specific way to achieve this?**

Example:
Let's say I've userA, userB, userC. Now all 3 users have started the process let's called it processToFetchVideos. Now if userA calls a stop API with its request-id, I want to stop the execution of processToFetchVideos for userA only, for userB and userC it should continue.

**Note: I don't want to kill and restart the server.**

```
app.post('/trigger', async(req, res) => {
    const requestId = uuid.v1()
    processToFetchVideos(requestId) 
    // Here I'm not waiting for procees to finish
    return res.status(200).json({msg: "Success", requestId})
}) 

app.post('/stop', async(req, res) => {
    const {requestId} = req.body;
    // Need help here how can I stop processToFetchVideos() function.
})


processToFetchVideos = (requestId) => {
    /* Code to fetch videos and write it to DB, no need to 
      return any response for trigger API. */
}
```

Comment: okay, so.... what do you actually need help with? You already have everything in place here from your description: you have specific request IDs that you can use as payload for a new API call for to whatever (micro)service you're running to cancel that particular job.

Comment: I'm not having a microservice for a particular request, It's just a normal function that runs on the backend through trigger API. I want to know how can I cancel the execution of that perticular request

Comment: given that you've shown no code whatsoever: I strongly doubt anyone can help you with that one. If you return request ids, presumably your code already tracks requests tied to ids, and you can trivially write a new API endpoint that can use that ids to find the associated request and then kill it off.

Comment: okay, I've modified the question with some example code, which might help someone to understand it more.

Comment: that code still won't let us help you though: if processToFetchVideos takes a request id, then write a new killVideoFetching(requestid) and tap into the same system that's doing the processing, so that your code updates a value that gets checked in the "process" function. Whether you do that through a simple object with some boolean vars, or a db record, or anything, is entirely up to you and we can't sensibly comment on without a deep dive into how your code works, which is not what Stackoveflow is for.

Comment: Will your 'processToFetchVideos' function return any values?

Comment: yes, processToFetchVideos will return some value